# How to disable plugins in Firefox but keep them enabled in incognito

Tags: firefox, plugins

So I know how you enable/disable plugins and how to enable/disable plugins for private mode.

But I have a few plugins that I don't need when browsing normally so I want to keep them disabled. Now when browsing in incognito I would rather have these plugins enabled.

But basically when you disable plugins you disable them for both normal mode as incognito mode is there no method to disable it for the normal mode only but to keep them enabled in incognito?

Thanks in Advance!

PS: I am asking this for firefox, but if its possible for chrome feel free to answer that aswell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that feature is not available. The rationale for being able to disable addons in incognito mode is that some addons can defeat incognito mode's features. This is actually the opposite of what you're requesting.

You can work around this by creating a new Firefox profile and setting it to forget everything when you close the browser.

Profiles can be created and launched by typing `about:profiles` in the addressbar. You can bookmark it for easy access. I'd also recommend setting a non-default theme to make windows from that profile more distinctive.

Then go to *Preferences* → *Privacy and Security* and enable *Delete cookies and site data when Firefox is closed*. Make sure that preserving tabs is disabled and strict tracker protection is enabled to make it closer to actual incognito mode.

Comment: Oh okay good to know that there is some sort of workaround to be able to achieve this, even though it isn't the same as using incognito normally with these plugins. I'll accept this as the solution to this answer since there is no straightforward solution (ofcourse workarounds not included) to this at this point in time.